# Progressão Geométrica em python

Tags: python

Me ajudem a fazer uma progressão geométrica em python que leia um valor inicial e uma razão e imprima uma sequencia com 10 valores.

Comment: Você já tem algum código que você já tentou?

Comment: https://ideone.com/JI9cnf

Answer (score 3):

Assumindo que uma [progressão geométrica](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progress%C3%A3o_geom%C3%A9trica) seja algo como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em `Python` isso poderia ser calculado da seguinte maneira:

```
a = 2
r = 5
tam = 10

pg = [ a * r ** (n - 1) for n in range(1, tam + 1) ]

print( pg )
```

Saída:

```
[2, 10, 50, 250, 1250, 6250, 31250, 156250, 781250, 3906250]
```

Answer (score 0):

Pois não.

O primeiro passo é conseguir input do usuário. Pra isso, usamos a função `input`.

```
entrada_str = input('n: ')  # '232'
```

Infelizmente, isso nos dá uma string, que é inútil para nossos cálculos.

Pra converter a string a um número inteiro, podemos fazer um dicionário (par chave-valor) de cada caractere da string pra seu respectivo número. Isso é, algo assim:

```
{'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2...}
```

Infelizmente, isso é terrivelmente chato de digitar. O módulo `string` vai nos ajudar trazendo todos os dígitos possíveis:

```
import string

string.digits  # '0123456789'
```

Agora temos que criar um dicionário e atribuir aos pares valor-chave cada caractere de dígito com seu valor numérico equivalente. Definimos um gerador `enumerar` pra nos auxiliar a contar os números:

```
def enumerar(iterador):
    contador = 0
    for elemento in iterador:
        yield contador, elemento
        contador += 1

dicionario_digitos = {}
for i, digito in enumerar(string.digits):
    dicionario_digitos[digito] = i

print(dicionario_digitos)  # {'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, ...}
```

Ótimo. Podemos usar nosso dicionário pra converter a string original em um número inteiro agora.

```
total = 0
for i, caractere in enumerar(entrada_str):
    total += dicionario_digitos[caractere] * int('1' + '0' * (len(entrada_str) - i - 1))
print(total)  # 232
```

Agora temos que inventar a multiplicação. Criamos uma classe `Inteiro` e sobrecarregamos um operador qualquer pra que possamos usá-lo com um `int` e obter o resultado da multiplicação entre um e outro. Suponhamos que usamos o operador `@`.

```
class Inteiro:

    def __init__(self, valor):
        self.valor = valor

    def __matmul__(self, other):
        total = 0
        for i in range(other):
            total += self.valor
        return total

a = Inteiro(2)
print(a @ 3)  # 6
```

Sucesso!

Isso significa que finalmente podemos ter o que o senhor nos comandou. Suponhamos que o fator desejado seja 7. Então, basta fazer

```
for i in range(10):
    print(Inteiro(7) @ (total ** i))
```

Resultado:

```
2
464
107648
24974336
5794045952
1344218660864
311858729320448
72351225202343936
16785484246943793152
3894232345290960011264
```